# How to dynamically load JSON data in a table with AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs, object

I have a column chooser widget that contains list of names with unique IDs. There is a backend service that returns an Object with the data.

```
output = {
id: 1, name: "john", title: "developer",
id: 2, name: "mark", title: "designer",
id: 3, name: "sally", title: "HR"
...
}
```

I need to create a table in html using AngularJS that dynamically adds/removes rows as I select the specific ID from my column choser.

```
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyController">
        <table border = "1">
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Title</th>
            </tr>
            <tbody ng-repeat="m in output">
                <tr>
                    <td>{{m.id}}</td>
                    <td>{{m.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{m.title}}</td>                    
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
</div>
```

What should I add in my controller to get the desired result? Is there any way other than using $scope?

Comment: `output` variable should be an Array of Objects.

Comment: what do you mean by column chooser?

Comment: is there a select box to select which columns to be displayed?

Answer (score 0):

Your output object should be an array of objects:
Example Blow:

```
$sope.output = [
   { id: 1, name: "john", title: "developer"} ,
   { id: 2, name: "mark", title: "designer"} ,
   { id: 3, name: "sally", title: "HR"}
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Backend service should return an Object with the data in below format to iterate that in the HTML template.

```
[{id: 1, name: "john", title: "developer"},
{id: 2, name: "mark", title: "designer"},
{id: 3, name: "sally", title: "HR"}]
```

**Demo :**

```js
var module = angular.module('myApp',[]);

module.controller("myController", function($scope) {
      $scope.output = [{id: 1, name: "john", title: "developer"},
    {id: 2, name: "mark", title: "designer"},
    {id: 3, name: "sally", title: "HR"}];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
        <table border = "1">
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Title</th>
            </tr>
            <tbody ng-repeat="m in output">
                <tr>
                    <td>{{m.id}}</td>
                    <td>{{m.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{m.title}}</td>                    
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this, try it and let me know

Select the multiple column names to be displayed by holding `ctrl` key

```js
angular.module("MyApp", [])

  .controller("MyController", ($scope) => {

    $scope.columns = []

    $scope.output = [{
        id: 1,
        name: "john",
        title: "developer"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "mark",
        title: "designer"
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: "sally",
        title: "HR"
      }
    ]

    $scope.getColumns = () => {
      return Object.keys($scope.ouput).filter(name => $scope.columns.indexOf(name) !== -1)
    }

  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyController">
  <select ng-model="columns" multiple>
    <option value="id">ID</option>
    <option value="name">Name</option>
    <option value="title">Title</option>
  </select>
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <th ng-repeat="column in columns">{{column}}</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="m in output">
        <td ng-repeat="column in columns">{{m[column]}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```